# Shape Button with reducing height in CSS

Tags: css, button

We require guidance to create a button CSS like below . Kindly let us know if its possible with CSS, let us know if there are any examples from which i can evolve the shape.
[image]

Comment: Tried codepen? http://codepen.io/sebastianschrama/pen/gadyKm

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Easy with pseudoelement :before

```css
.box {
  height:40px;
  width:200px;
  background-color:Orange;
  position:relative;
  display:inline-block;
  border-radius:0px 0px 5px 0;
  text-align:center;
  font-weight:bold;
  font-family:arial;
  color:#fff;
  font-size:20px;
  line-height:50px;  
}
.box:before {
  position:absolute;
  content: "";
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-top: 20px solid Orange;
  border-right: 197px solid transparent;
  bottom:-20px;
  left:0;
  border-radius:0px 0px 0px 5px;  
}
```

```html
<div class="box">+ADD NEW</div>
```

Comment: looks pretty good, but on the right bottom corner there's a one pixel high line

Comment: I twiked it a bit. still not perfect but better

Comment: @AlvaroMenéndez Thanks So Much ! It Worked :)